# css transition like 3d box

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am looking for achieve effect like in this website: [link to website](http://www.tequilla.me/) ( this is not promoting website )

there is facebook icon that using transition, but I can't I can't reverse engineering effect by my own.

[image: on] ====> [image]

This is my try:

### JsBin:

http://jsbin.com/ofIJEVO/5/edit

### HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class='off'>off</div>
    <div class='on'>on</div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.off {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.on {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orangered;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
          transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}

.box:hover .off{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg);
          transform: rotateY(90deg);
}

.box:hover .on{
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
     -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you tried to _inspect_ the element to see what _styles_ it has ?

Comment: yes, but I failed. I can't reverse engineering it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hwsb5/)** is the working link according to your requirement.

[THis is the tutorial link](http://webbb.be/blog/little-css3-3d-hover-effects/) and Demo [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/5231260)

is what will help you.

this function is doing trick rest is your css.

```
  $("#facebook").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).css({"transform":"rotateY(100deg)"})

    });
    $("#facebook").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css({"transform":"rotateY(0deg)"})

    });
```

Comment: Where to position images and how to rotate them to achieve wanted effect ? so far I can't figure it out with this example though it is very helpful.

Comment: pleasure @Ing.MichalHudak